# Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) Port Forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat, xbox360, ics

When connecting my XBox One to my laptop via ICS I am able to open port 3074 required to receive an open NAT type, but other ports do not appear to open when added using the same method as 3074, using the Advanced Settings on my Wi-Fi adapter.

I am also using a crossover cable, and the firewall is disabled; I'm routing through Open-WRT with UPnP enabled. I have also tried forwarding the ports from the router to the Wi-Fi adapter, though this was not required for 3074, this also did not open alternative ports such as 3075.

Bridging is not an option, as I require ICS for network testing my indie game.

**XBox One**
IP: 192.168.137.20
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.137.1

**Ethernet** 
IP: 192.168.137.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: Empty

**Wi-Fi (ICS)**
IP: 192.168.1.151
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. This is a clear and well-formed question. +1

Comment: @CanadianLuke you're right, been switching to often between the 2. Ok now.

Answer (score 0):

So i just found out that this is indeed possible. NiJo was right. Under the **sharing** tab click **settings** then **add**.

Here you can enter the ports required for your device connect via ICS. In this case the xbox.

Under ip, enter the ip of ICS device (here: 192.168.137.20). Then the ports.

Make sure to place a checkmark in the list when you're done entering the settings.

Now the port (in this case: 3074) is accessible from 192.168.1.151:3074

Comment: On my Windows Machine I can SSH to root@192.168.137.58 or root@192.168.137.50, for some reason my Linux box appears to have 2 IPs on the internal subnet. When I add a port forwarding rule for port 22 and connect to 192.168.1.232 via SSH nothing happens. I can RDP to 192.168.1.232.

Comment: Now the Linux Box is 192.168.137.99

Comment: How to make sure the device always gets 192.168.137.20? Is there a place to configure static IP assignment in the DHCP of the ICS host? Or do I have to set a static IP on my device?